# Add item with reference in other collection fails

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

foodtruck.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Items = require('./items.js');


var FoodTruckSchema = new Schema({
    foodtruck_name:String,
    foodtruck_location:String,
    foodtruck_rating:{type:Number,default:5},
    foodtruck_total_votes:{type:Number,default:0},
    foodtruck_tag:String,
    foodtruck_timing:String,
    foodtruck_cusine:String,
    foodtruck_img:String,
    foodtruck_logo:String,
    item_list: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'items'}]
},{ versionKey: false });



module.exports = mongoose.model('foodtruck',FoodTruckSchema);
```

items.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    no_of_times_ordered:Number,
    item_name:String,
    item_tag:String,
    item_category:String,
    item_illustrations:[String],
    item_stock:Number,   //0 available 1 last 5 items 2 not available
    item_quantity_ordered:{type:Number,default:0},
    item_price:Number,
    item_img:String,
    no_of_likes:{type:Number,default:0}
},{ versionKey: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model('items',ItemSchema);
```

No, I want to add new item. The new item is added, but somehow its reference is not conveyed to the **foodtruck.item_list**. The query that I am trying is as below:

```
var addItem = function(req, res) {
    var foodtruck_id = req.body.foodtruck_id;
    var newItem = new item();
    var itemList = [];
    newItem.item_name = req.body.item_name;
    newItem.item_tag = req.body.item_tag;
    newItem.item_category = req.body.item_category;

    for (var key in req.body) {
        if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key == 'item_illustrations') {
                newItem.item_illustrations = req.body[key];
            }
        }
    }
    newItem.item_stock = req.body.item_status;
    newItem.item_price = req.body.item_price;

    if ((foodtruck_id) && (foodtruck_id.trim() != '')) {
        foodtruck.findById(foodtruck_id.trim(), function(err, foodtrucks) {
            if (err)
                res.json({
                    status: '500',
                    message: 'There is no data available'
                });

            newItem.save();
            foodtrucks.item_list.push(newItem);
            foodtrucks.save();
            console.log(foodtrucks);

            foodtruck.findById(foodtruck_id.trim()).populate('item_list').exec(function(err, foodtrucks) {
                if (err) res.json({
                    status: '500',
                    message: 'There is no data available'
                });
                res.send({
                    status: '200',
                    message: 'Review List',
                    data: foodtrucks
                });
            });
        });
    } else {
        res.json({
            status: '404',
            message: 'Please enter valid foodtruck id'
        });
    }

};
```

Here,item gets added,but foodtruck does not have the reference of it. So, how can I add the reference of the item?

Screenshot of newly added item in foodtruck collection

[image: query image]

Comment: why dont you pass a callback in foodtruck.save() and see if its getting saved, if not then what is the error

Comment: even,I tried to do that. There is no error. It is just that reference is not there there inside "item_list"

Comment: at what point are you stuck?

Comment: Basically,what I am trying to do is., when new item is added for particular foodtruck, its reference should be added in the foodtruck collection as well.

Comment: is that new item being successfully created? Also, `newItem.item_illustrations = req.body[key];` -> is this correct?

Comment: yes,it is successfully created, its just that reference is not added in foodtruck collection, so that it would not show in populate query

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the whole item instead of the ObjectId of the newly created item. You need to save the new item and then in the callback of the save you will have to push the `_id` of newly created item in the `item_list`.

Instead of simple save Try this:

```
//do everything inside the calllback of the save
newItem.save(function(err,savedItem){
    if(!err){
        foodtrucks.item_list.push(savedItem._id);
        foodtrucks.save();//youcan use callback here also to handle the errors
        console.log(foodtrucks);

        foodtruck.findById(foodtruck_id.trim()).populate('item_list').exec(function(err, foodtrucks) {
            if (err) res.json({
                status: '500',
                message: 'There is no data available'
            });
            res.send({
                status: '200',
                message: 'Review List',
                data: foodtrucks
            });
        });
    }else{
        res.json({
            status: '500',
            message: 'Error while saving new item'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Item gets referenced in foodtruck collection when I checked through robomongo. But somehow when I put populate query, the newly added item is not reflected in the output json response

Comment: did you try my method?

Comment: Yes, I tried your method and Item gets referenced in foodtruck collection when I checked through robomongo. But somehow when I put populate query, the newly added item is not reflected in the output json response

Comment: can you show me how it is stored in  robomongo, is there an difference between the newly pushed and old item objectIds?

Comment: I have added image of queried "foodtruck" collection in my updated question.It is from robomongo

Comment: It is alright, the code should work, can you show me your pupulate query?

Comment: It is the same,as you gave me. I copied the exact query posted by you

Comment: Okay, then I think it should work, it worked in other cases right?